# how to use infowindow (google map API) to get back the ID of the selected location

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, google-maps-api-3

I am displaying a list of locations (that i get through ViewBag for now) on a map and ask the user to choose one of them.

I have populated my infowindows with HTML code by looping through the list of locations.

now when the user clicks on one of the buttons in the infowindow ("Choose this one"), I want to update the view model (Venue) to include Venue.Id = the choosen location and submit back to the controller so update the database. how can I do such a thing ?

thanks a lot for your help.

here is my script code:

```
  @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <section class="scripts">  
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           Initialize();
       });

       function Initialize() {

           google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
           var rabat = new google.maps.LatLng(34.019657, -6.831833);
           var mapOptions = {
               zoom: 11,
               center: rabat,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.G_NORMAL_MAP
           };

           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

           var list =

          @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(((IEnumerable<KayenChiMVC.Models.Venue>)ViewBag.TheVenue).Select(v => new 
                { 
                    venueId = v.VenueID, 
                    venueName = v.Name,
                    venueDistrict = v.District,
                    venueType = v.SurfaceType,
                    venueLat = v.Latitude, 
                    venueLon = v.Longitude 
                })
            ));


           var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

           for(var i=0; i<list.length;i++){

               var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(list[i].venueLat, list[i].venueLon);

               var html = "<table>" +
                "<tr><td>Nom:</td>" + "<td> " + list[i].venueName +" </td> </tr>" + 
                "<tr><td>Quartier:</td>" + "<td> " + list[i].venueDistrict +" </td> </tr>" +
                "<tr><td>Type de surface:</td>" + "<td> " + list[i].venueType +" </td> </tr>" +

                "<tr><td></td><td><input type='button' value='Choisir ce terrain' onclick=''/></td></tr>";


               createMarker(pos, list[i].venueName, html);


               function createMarker(pos,title, html){

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    'position': pos,
                    'map': map,
                    'title': list[i].venueName
                });

                marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png');

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(html);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });

               }
           }


       }

      </script>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a data-id attribute to your input to hold the venue id.

```
<input id="myButton" type="button" data-id="123" value="Choose this one" />
```

and get the data-id attribute in javascript

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {
    console.log(this.getAttribute('data-id')); // will log '123'
};
```